# Shared VMware folders between Ubuntu/OSX causes "invisble characters" and syntax errors

Tags: macos, ubuntu, filesystems, vmware-fusion

I'm experincing an annoying issue, which (I think) is caused by a discrepancy between Ubuntu filesystem and Mac OSX filesystem. It seems to be a general problem, which can occur for anybody using Mac OSX, VMware Fusion and Ubuntu as guest.

**My setup**

- My host is Mac OSX where all source files are located.
- My guest OS is Ubuntu Server (non-gui) where all dev tools and compilers are
  installed (python, php etc).
- My virtualization software is VMware Fusion.

I couldn't get VMware Tools to work, so I followed these steps, to share files from OSX to Ubuntu:
[Getting an error trying to set up shared folders on an Ubuntu instance of VMWare Fusion running on OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/511679/getting-an-error-trying-to-set-up-shared-folders-on-an-ubuntu-instance-of-vmware/522337#522337)

Once again: files are located on OSX, shared to guest (Ubuntu) where PHP can read them.

**Case Study**

I've done some digging around with the PHP framework [Laravel's](http://laravel.com/) inbuilt [Artisan commands](http://laravel.com/docs/artisan?/docs/artisan/). All of the following commands are run from the Ubuntu (guest)

First time, this will work fine:

```
php artisan
```

I can also rebuild the source files just fine:

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

However, as the files have been rebuilt, this no longer works:

```
php artisan
```

... and results in this syntax error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'F' in /mnt/hgfs/www/tmi/api/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php on line 1646
```

The problem disappears if I remount the folder with the source code:

```
sudo mount /mnt/hgfs/www
```

Now I can again run the following without problems:

```
php artisan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question turned out to be somewhat specific to PHP. Closing and moving the question to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814601/php-syntax-error-when-files-are-added-to-vmware-host-from-guest).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be the expand program, that replaces tabs with whitespace.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. This doesn't provide a lot of information to help address the OP. Please provide more detail and explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even when no tabs are replaced, and the file is literally identical, it will still yield a syntax error, until saved.