# VMWare and Linux/Ubuntu Shared Folders

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, shared-folders

I've been unable to get shared folders to show up at all. I've peeled through forums and tried installing, and reinstalling VMWare Tools…then [seeing maybe those don't work at all](https://superuser.com/questions/511679/getting-an-error-trying-to-set-up-shared-folders-on-an-ubuntu-instance-of-vmware)?

Whatever I'm doing isn't working. I saw one tutorial suggest toggling Shared Folders (in VMWare), but when I do I always get the message:

> Unable to update run-time folder sharing status: There was an error mounting >Shared Folders file system inside the guest operating system

Running Ubuntu 14.04 on VMWare Fusion 6.0.5. I'm super-new to all of this, I know enough to open Terminal and try inputting random things strangers tell me online, but that's about it.

For context: I'm using Ubuntu to transfer DCP (Digital Cinema Package) files onto Linux-formatted drives, so shared folders would really help out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want share the clipboard in Mint after installing the VMware tools, then you have to run these commands in Terminal.

cd Desktop/vmware-tools-distrib

sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d

Make sure your vmware-tools-distrib is on the desktop. Just extract the folder to the desktop.

2. If you want to share partitions, have a look at my tutorial:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/19657-vmware-player-share-partitions-between-host-guest.html#post188991

Comment: Thanks whs! vmware-tools-distrib doesn't fix the problem :\ From some other reading around I've done, it sounds as if the tools are broken and/or out of date?

The tutorial really didn't help as I'm on a mac with VMWare Fusion.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that Fusion worked differently.